# Wordpress on WAMP: Need to change site looking for assets on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have a wordpress site hosted on WAMP on my local PC. I want other people on my network to view this website but when I tested it from another PC none of the stylesheets, scripts etc are being loaded. I troubleshooted it and found this is because it's looking for those files on localhost. How can I change it to look for those files relative to the folder? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using my IP address as the site path in Wordpress/Settings/General

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is a bit like moving the site to another domain. Because WP records the domain name in its database when you install it, it thinks its domain is localhost.
Now you are getting to it by lets say using your ip address 192.168.0.10 this is considered a new domain name and when it attempts to server various resources it is still using the original domain name of localhost it cannot find those resources on the other PC's.

You can find out what you need to do here on the worpress site [Changing the site url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)